# Unable to trigger constructor level validation

Tags: java, validation, bean-validation, spring-annotations, spring-validator

I'm unable to run constructor parameter validation using only annotations.

My Code:

```
@Data
@Validated
public class TestConstructorLevel
{
    private int a;
    private int b;

    private Integer nullValue;

    public TestConstructorLevel( int a, int b, @NotNull Integer nullValue )
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
        this.nullValue = nullValue;
    }

}
```

I expect when I do in some service

```
new TestConstructorLevel(1, 2, null)
```

I get **ConstraintViolationException**, because of **@NotNull**, but this doesn't work.

The only variant i get it working, when i trigger the validation manually, like here:

```
validator.forExecutables().validateConstructorParameters(
            ReflectionUtils.accessibleConstructor( TestConstructorLevel.class, int.class, int.class, Integer.class ),
            new Object[] { 2,1, null } );
```

but this isn't suitable.

*I tried to create TestConstructorLevel class as Spring bean and nothing changed.*

So my question is: **What annotation i need to use to trigger validation on a Constructor.**

PS. It's SpringBoot application,

Answer (score 0):

You can't possibly change what a constructor does by just adding an annotation to it or to its arguments.

An annotation is just that: an annotation. It just provides some metadata regarding the constructor argument.

The Validator can use this metadata to do its validation job. But the constructor stays just that: a constructor.

Comment: I don't try to change anything in the class constructor, I just want to validate constructor parameters.

The same as validation of the method parameters here:
`code`

@Service
@Validated
public class MyService{
    public boolean methodParameterValidation( @NotNull Integer value )
    {
        return false;
    }
}

`code`

Comment: You **expect** that calling the constructor will throw a validation exception, just because you have added an annotation to one of its arguments. I'm trying to explain that this is an unrealistic expectation, bacause annotations are not annotations. They don't change the behavior of the constructor as you expect them to do.

Comment: Validating arguments of a Spring bean method only works because Spring doesn't just call the method: it detects the annotation, intercepts the calls to the method thanks to a proxy, invokes the validation API to validate the arguments, and then finally calls the method if the arguments are valid.

Comment: I meant "annotations are **just** annotations" in my previous comment.

Comment: I don't understand the 
 fundamental difference between method and constructor which doesn't allow to apply automatic spring validation to constructor. Why we can validate method parameters, but can't validate constructor parameters?

Comment: I explained that in my previous comment. Create a simple test where you create an instance of your service using new MyService(). then call the method annotated method with invalid arguments. You'll have no exception either. Because the annotation doesn't change anything to the code of the method. Again, it works when you use it as an injected Spring bean because Spring detects the annotation, creates a proxy around the bean which intercepts the method calls, and invokes the validation API (the same way you've done it) before actually calling the method.

Comment: Look, I tried to manipulate only with Spring Beans. There are links to github
[Incorrect bean](https://github.com/4atlanin/java-validation/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/validation/validators/configs/ValidationConfig.java)
[Constructor of the bean i would like to validate](https://github.com/4atlanin/java-validation/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/validation/validators/domain/TestConstructorLevelAnnotation.java)
And here i injects bean
[link](https://github.com/4atlanin/java-validation/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/validation/ValidationService.java#L28)

Comment: That's a completely different question. The question is now "does Spring support bean constructor validation"? And I don't think it does. Frankly, I would just write an if check in the constructor.

Comment: You are right. Spring doesn't doesn't have such feature. Maybe because the constructor level validation looks like something useless.

Thank you!